# Why does `eval-when-compile` run at file load and byte-compiled to .elc?

Tags: elisp, coding-conventions

Common idiom to workaround macro expansion or resolve warning about undefined variables during byte-compilation:

```
(eval-when-compile
  (require 'cl-lib))
```

But this `require ...` compiled into `.elc` file! I found that `cl-eval-when` have proper semantic (according to name).

Normally we don't need for `require` as site file and `package.el`

For example I want to byte-compile my `.emacs` which uses some external macros, but silently pass through if there are no such package:

```
(cl-eval-when 'compile
  (condition-case err
      (require 'w3m-util)
    (error (byte-compile-warn "Failed by: %S" err))))
(w3m-util-DEPENDENT-CODE ...)
```

Another way to do this is:

```
(ignore-error
   (require 'w3m-util)
   (w3m-util-DEPENDENT-CODE ...))
```

But now we are not a top level form...

Do I properly fill that `eval-when-compile` name do something that is not expected from its name?

Comment: FWIW, the latter two snippets do not have the same behavior. The former does not protect `w3m-DEPENDENT-CODE` from a missing `w3m-util`.

Comment: `(when (require 'w3m-util nil t) (w3m-util-DEPENDENT-CODE...))`

Comment: `(when (require 'w3m-util nil t) ...)` is nice idiom! But I try to make perfect `.emacs` file, not a library. So have in mind delayed (on-request) code loading with help of auto-loading. For this reason I extensively use `eval-after-load`, asked `require` needs only to make byte-compilation success with macro expansion.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Did you ask Emacs what `eval-when-compile` is supposed to do?

`C-h f eval-when-compile` tells you that it evaluates the arg also at load time:

```
eval-when-compile is a Lisp macro in `byte-run.el'.

(eval-when-compile &rest BODY)

Like ‘progn’, but evaluates the body at compile time if you’re compiling.
Thus, the result of the body appears to the compiler as a quoted
constant.  In interpreted code, this is entirely equivalent to
‘progn’, except that the value of the expression may be (but is
not necessarily) computed at load time if eager macro expansion
is enabled.
```

It says that if interpreted it is like `progn`.  And it explicitly repeats this.

A function or macro name seldom reflects the behavior perfectly.  But in this case it sounds like you are looking for a different behavior, which might be called `eval-only-when-compile`.

Comment: `eval-only-when-compile` name help me understand point to name `eval-when-compile`, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

To evaluate code only on compilation stage use `eval-when` macros which is dated by RMS in 1993-07-30.

`cl-eval-when` appeared in 2012-06-03 from Stefan Monnier and it is not available for Emacs 22.x (if you care, I do).

For example you like to get rid of `Warning: assignment to free variable` in:

```
(setq auto-revert-interval 2)
```

just add above that line:

```
(eval-when 'compile (require 'autorevert))
```

Note that this is useful only for byte compilation of `.emacs` file. If you develop a library you should do `require` or split library file into separate and load only required features.

Comment: To avoid variable warnings, you just need `(defvar auto-revert-interval)`

Comment: I use `defvar` solution in many cases but also look for *stronger* solution. I can mistype name or package can remove definition and compilation checker would be silent in such cases.

Comment: `Symbol’s function definition is void: eval-when`. Btw, adding a "only require on compile" code to a library is exactly what I trying to do. There is one function that is only used in python-mode. Doing a `(require 'python)` always just because of that single function results in ≈110ms of excess delay when the package gets loaded, that's ridiculous.

Comment: I think `eval-when` is supposed to be a `cl-eval-when`, from `cl-lib` or `cl-macs`. That works.

Comment: Note for people finding this in recent years: `eval-when` is documented as being obsolete since Emacs 27.1. `cl-eval-when` is recommended instead.